# SSH to box and edit XML file in Java code?

Tags: java, xml, ssh

I am trying to SSH to a windows box (got that working) and edit an XML file in Java code.  Obviously I could edit it over SSH using VI or emacs, but how would I do that in code?  I am using the ganymed-ssh2 library to achieve the SSH.  I could write a batch file on the windows box to do what I need to do, but I would rather not have to maintain another set of files on the box.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Download the file (scp), modify it, upload it again.

Comment: Is that a common practice?  I thought about doing something like that but it seemed like it wasn't a smart idea -  like destroying a file and rebuilding it, too many things could go wrong.  I'm self-taught, so I don't know a lot of how things are done, other than how I do it.

Comment: Many more things things are going to go wrong trying to run VI or emacs from java. Start by assuming the file is local, parse it, change it, write new version/etc. When that all works, sort out the ssh bits.

Comment: Oh, no way was I going to try and run VI in Java :-).  I was just wondering if there was a parse/edit it using terminal commands, because those I could execute easily in Java.